# Having trouble aligning an image with link and text via html and css

Tags: html, css

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXLdJZ)

In this case I'm wanting the image to be on the left then the authors name centered next to the image and then below those I'm trying to center the buttons. I had the picture and the buttons centered but when I add the authors name it all goes off.

Also how would I go about make everything a bit smaller. I've tried adjusting the height and width but then the author image ends up outside the section.

```css
.authorbio {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px dotted #870505;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 55%;
  height: 55%;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.authorbio>h1 {
  vertical-align: right;
  text-align: center;
}
.authorbio>img {
  border: 1px solid #870505;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* social links
--------------------------------------- */

a.sociallinks {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(76, 68, 68)), to(rgb(22, 21, 21)));
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a.sociallinks:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(224, 0, 0)), to(rgb(61, 2, 2)));
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a.sociallinks:visited {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(96, 96, 96)), to(rgb(2, 2, 2)));
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a.sociallinks:active {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(30, 30, 30)), to(rgb(70, 70, 70)));
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="authorbio">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mO3gFua5L._UX250_.jpg" alt="Paula Cappa" />
  <h1><a href="https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/6553133.Paula_Cappa" target="_blank" title="Paula Cappa on Goodreads">Paula Cappa</a></h1>
  <br /><a class="sociallinks" href="http://www.amazon.com/Greylock-Paula-Cappa-ebook/dp/B0168XVNZS/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top?ie=UTF8" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Greylock on Amazon">Amazon</a>  <a class="sociallinks" href="http://www.facebook.com/paula.cappa.94"
  target="_blank" title="Author Paula Cappa on Facebook">Facebook</a>  <a class="sociallinks" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26887306-greylock" target="_blank" title="Greylock on Goodreads">Goodreads</a>  <a class="sociallinks" href="https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/582884"
  target="_blank" title="Greylock on Smashwords">Smashwords</a>  <a class="sociallinks" href="https://twitter.com/PaulaCappa1" target="_blank" title="Paula Cappa Twitter">Twitter</a>  <a class="sociallinks" href="https://paulacappa.wordpress.com/" target="_blank"
  title="Paula Cappa Wordpress">Website</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this **working
[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/wilman/pen/pgXyyw)**

I just made the title `inline-block` and adjusted the width accordingly with the useful `calc` property.

```css
.authorbio>h1{
  vertical-align: right;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 175px); /* substract the image's width + some extra */
}
```

Then put the links inside a container to apply some `flex` properties (`justify-content: center` did the magic).

```html
<div class="sociallinks-container">
 <!-- put your links here -->
 ...
</div>
```

```css
.sociallinks-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* this prevents the items wrapping to another line */
  justify-content: center; /* this centers the links */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, you have only to replace image and link addresses.I wrote a full code for you.try this.if this is not the case tell me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hover</title>

<style type="text/css">
  body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }

div.bio{
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px dotted red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div.autorimage{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div.autorimage img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.authorlink{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div.authorlink a{
  font-size: 45px;
}

div.authorlink a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

div.buttonsetone{
  width: 100%;
}

div.buttonsettwo{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

div.buttonsetone div{
  width: auto;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div.buttonsetone div:hover{
  background-color: red;
}

div.buttonsetone div a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;

}

div.buttonsettwo div{
  width: auto;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div.buttonsettwo div:hover{
  background-color: red;
}

div.buttonsettwo div a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="bio">
    <div class="autorimage"><img src=""></div><br/>
    <div class="authorlink"><a href="#">Paula Cappa</a></div><br/>
    <div class="buttonsetone">
      <div><a href="#">Amazon</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Goodreads</a></div>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="buttonsettwo">
      <div><a href="#">Smashwords</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Twitter</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">WebSite</a></div>
    </div>
 </div>


</body>



</html>
```